# wait until first hook is complete before fetching data

Tags: asynchronous, react-hooks, graphql, apollo, gqless

I have this custom hook which fetches the `query.me` data from graphql. The `console.log` statement shows that this hook is running a number of times on page load, but only 1 of those `console.logs()` contains actual data.

```
import { useCustomQuery } from '../api-client';

export const useMe = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useCustomQuery({
  query: async (query) => {
      return getFields(query.me, 'account_id', 'role', 'profile_id');
    },
  });
  console.log(data ? data.account_id : 'empty');

  return { isLoading, error, me: data };
};
```

I then have this other hook which is supposed to  use the id's from the above hook to fetch more data from the server.

```
export const useActivityList = () => {
  const { me, error } = useMe();

  const criteria = { assignment: { uuid: { _eq: me.profile_id } } } as appointment_bool_exp;

  const query = useQuery({
    prepare({ prepass, query }) {
      prepass(
        query.appointment({ where: criteria }),
        'scheduled_at',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
      );
    },
    suspense: true,
  });

  const activityList = query.appointment({ where: criteria });

  return {
    activityList,
    isLoading: query.$state.isLoading,
  };
};
```

The problem I am facing is that the second hook seems to call the first hook when `me` is still undefined, thus erroring out. How do I configure this, so that I only access the `me` when the values are populated?

I am bad with async stuff...

Comment: It depends. The library you are using to fetch data probably has a disable flag so use it to disable if from running until the conditions are right. Or, you can call async functions within a useEffect based on your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In the second hook do an early return if the required data is not available.

```
export const useActivityList = () => {
  const { me, error } = useMe();

  if (!me) {
    return null;
    // or another pattern that you may find useful is to set a flag to indicate that this query is idle e.g.
    // idle = true;
  }

  const criteria = { assignment: { uuid: { _eq: me.profile_id } } } as appointment_bool_exp;

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That results in `React Hook "useQuery" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?`

Comment: Oh sorry, I answered too quickly lol. What library are you using for useQuery? It probably has an option to enable/disable the query. In which case you could pass `!!me`

Comment: It's based off apollo

Comment: Looks like you need to use `useTransactionQuery` and set the `skip` option to `!!me` https://gqless.com/react/fetching-data#usetransactionquery